# TApplicationEvent.WillTerminate not triggered on iOS and Android

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

On both platforms, this event is not triggered when closing an application. How can I determine if an application is closed and not only in background mode.

Tested on iOS 8.3 and Android lollipop.

"By Closing" - meaning swiping the app up on iOS and clicking on the X on Android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect the termination of a program in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626892/how-to-detect-the-termination-of-a-program-in-android)

Comment: I solved it some time ago using the method in this link (same solution as the solution in the dublicate question, but easier to read) http://www.delphigear.cn/0/9863/go.aspx

Answer (score 3):

both of those user events are considered *force terminate* events and don't receive the `WillTerminate` event.

If you want it to receive the `WillTerminate` event, then you'll have to get the process to end naturally in the platform manner.

As noted in the [iOS App Lifecycle Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW1):

> In addition to the system terminating your app, the user can terminate your app explicitly using the multitasking UI. User-initiated termination has the same effect as terminating a suspended app. The app’s process is killed and no notification is sent to the app.

**Edit:**
If the application is in the foreground when you do the double-tap of home followed by a swipe then you *should* receive the notification (on iOS). If it's still running in the background (e.g. in the `EnteredBackground` handler), then it will receive the event. These are just ways of getting the event to trigger.

You should not be relying on receiving this event to cleanup your app. You should use the `EnteredBackground` handler to clean up as much as you can; assuming that the program may be terminated at any point after that *without* you receiving a termination event.

I can't find the exact reference for Android (I'm more familiar with iOS).

Comment: Petesh, the problem is with applications based on client/server connection. If the client reside on the iOS platform and the termination occurs only when the platform decides so, the server side cannot tell if the client is still connected.

Comment: True, but you should design your protocol to accept that the client can disconnect at any time; without signaling the fact. Use a heartbeat mechanism e.g. expect a heartbeat every 30 seconds, and if one is not received then assume the connection is gone after 60 (times can be fine tuned, timer can reset if the heartbeat is received before the connection state is torn down.

Comment: The app does detect that it is closed and the WillTerminate **is** fired (with the 2 x Home click + swipe up combination) if implemented in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The page links to the answer, and shows what to change to make it workfor XE6-XE8:
http://www.fmxexpress.com/handle-android-and-ios-lifecycle-events-in-delphi-xe5-firemonkey/

Comment: Hans,
I already saw that link prior to posting my question. The codes include a "WillTerminate" event which is never triggered unless the application is programmatically closed such as Application.Terminate. I thought that it might be a Delphi bug, but after reading articles not related to Delphi, it appears that there is just no way to have that event triggered within both platforms lifecycle.

Comment: In my iOS application it works. When i Double-click Home and swipe the app up, the WillTerminate is fired. I followed the description in my link, but I don't remember if I had to tweak other things to make it work...

Comment: Well Hans, try to remember if you had a tweak, because so far I couldn't make it work.